# Find name or alias of matched column in MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using `MATCH() AGAINST()` for full text search in my database. As since i wanted data from multiple tables, i created a `VIEW` and am using following format of query in `MARIADB`,

```
SELECT 
DAT1, DAT2, DAT3 
FROM VIEW1
WHERE 
MATCH (COL1) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) OR
MATCH (COL2) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) OR
MATCH (COL3) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Everything is working fine, but however i am looking for an addition output in query, and that is the **Column Name** i found search result in.

How can i fetch the name or alias of `COL1`, `COL2` and `COL3` of matched string in the output of query?

Comment: Wouldn't a `UNION` work better?

Comment: That does make alot of sense actually, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression in the `select`:

```
SELECT DAT1, DAT2, DAT3,
       CONCAT_WS(',',
                 (CASE WHEN MATCH(COL1) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0 THEN 'col1' END),
                 (CASE WHEN MATCH(COL2) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0 THEN 'col2' END),
                 (CASE WHEN MATCH(COL2) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0 THEN 'col3' END)
                ) as cols
FROM VIEW1
WHERE MATCH (COL1) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0 OR
      MATCH (COL2) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0 OR
      MATCH (COL3) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0;
```

Comment: One small doubt tho, does this have performance impact if i'm searching in, say, 7 columns? If yes, should i revert back to `LIKE %mona%`?

Comment: @Mercurial . . . The full text search should be faster than `like`.  However, with seven different indexes being used, you might want to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
( SELECT DAT1
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE MATCH (COL1) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) )
UNION ALL
( SELECT DAT2
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE MATCH (COL2) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) )
UNION ALL    
( SELECT DAT3
    FROM tbl3
    WHERE MATCH (COL3) AGAINST ('lisa mona aachen' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) )
```

`UNION ALL` is faster than the default (`UNION DISTINCT`), but use `DISTINCT` if there could be dups and you want them to be de-dupped.

No `VIEW` needed.  Or, you could make the above a `VIEW` with the text string waiting to be filled in (via an @variable?).