# Exploding tier 2 element of a PHP/Typescript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have this `PHP` code which is formatting the array for me,

```
    $data  = $dataQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($data)){
        $data_arr=array();
        $data_arr["records"]=array();
        $data_arr["records"] = $data;
    return $response
                ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
                ->withJson($data_arr, 200); 
    }
```

and my array is in format,

```
"records": [
{
"ID": "1",
"LOCATION": "LOC1#LOC2#LOC3",
"TIMEFRAME": "1601-1650",
"TYPE": "mythological#genre#portrait"
},
{
"ID": "2",
"LOCATION": "LOC2",
"TIMEFRAME": "1851-1900",
"TYPE": "landscape"
}
]
```

And i'm trying to format this like following by exploding all the `#`

```
"records": [
{
"ID": "1",
"LOCATION": [{LOC1, LOC2, LOC3}],
"TIMEFRAME": "1601-1650",
"TYPE": [{mythological, genre, portrait}]
},
{
"ID": "2",
"LOCATION": "LOC2",
"TIMEFRAME": "1851-1900",
"TYPE": "landscape"
}
]
```

Like this,

```
    //$data  = $dataQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($count['COUNT']>0/* &&count($data) */){
        $data_arr=array();
        $data_arr["records"]=array();

        //$data_arr["records"] = $data;
        while ($row = $dataQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $row_array=array();
            foreach ($row as $row_el){ 
                array_push($row_array, explode('#', $row_el));
            } 
            array_push($data_arr["records"], $row_array);
        }

    return $response
                ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
                ->withJson($data_arr, 200); 
    }
```

But this is generating following result,

```
"records":[ 
   [ 
      [ 
         "1"
      ],
      [ 
         "LOC1",
         "LOC2",
         "LOC3"
      ],
      [ 
         "1601-1650"
      ],
      [ 
         "mythological",
         "genre",
         "portrait"
      ]
   ],
   [ 
      [ 
         "2"
      ],
      [ 
         "LOC2"
      ],
      [ 
         "1851-1900"
      ],
      [ 
         "landscape"
      ]
   ]
]
```

**I am catching this response in Typescript/JavaScript so i can format this in client side too.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure if it wouldn't be easier to target the particular value individually rather than process the who record.

Basically you need to make sure you push the data back with the original key as well as the data.

The last part is that if there is only 1 element (as in `"ID": "1",`), stop it being an array by assigning the original value back to it...

```
foreach ($row as $key => $row_el){ 
    $expand = explode('#', $row_el);
    if ( count($expand) == 1 )  {
        $expand = $row_el;
    }
    $row_array[$key] = $expand;
}
```

Updated code for more levels of encoding...

```
$SQL_RE=array(
    "COUNT" => "5",
    "FORM" => "1&#painting",
    "SCHOOL" => "1&#German",
    "LOCATION" => "1&#Alte Pinakothek, Munich##2&#Kunsthistorisches Museum, Vienna##3&#Private collection",
    "TIMEFRAME" => "1&#1601-1650",
    "TYPE" => "1&#mythological##2&#genre##3&#portrait");

$row_array = [];
foreach ($SQL_RE as $key => $row_el){
    $expand2 = [];
    $l2 = [];
    $expand = explode('##', $row_el);
    foreach ( $expand as $key2 => $element2 )    {
        $expand2 = explode("&#", $element2 );
        if ( count($expand2) == 1 )  {
            $l2[$key2] = $element2;
        }
        else {
            $l2[$expand2[0]] = $expand2[1];
        }
    }
    if ( count($l2) == 1 && count($expand2) != 2 )  {
        $l2 = $row_el;
    }
    $row_array[$key] = $l2;
} 

print_r($row_array);
```

Comment: Your snippet worked perfectly! I was using this, `foreach ($row as $row_el_h => $row_el){ 
                    array_push($row_array[$row_el_h], explode('#',$row_el));
                } `, why wasn't this working? Also, is there a solution to this using `map` or other inbuilt libraries if i try to avoid `for` loops?

Comment: If you want to assign to a specific key in an array, `array_push()` isn't what you want - just assign it directly.  As for `array_map()` - it is (internally) almost the same as looping over the array, so this code is about the simplest you can get.

Comment: Umm, anyhow can you give me an example of this using `array_map`, it's getting complicated working with `tier 3`, Is it even ok to get into tier 3 elements? Complexity shouldn't arise as im using only 10 records per page.

Comment: Difficult to know how you mean, perhaps if you show an example it may help.

Comment: See [here](https://ideone.com/eI0Luk), My Frankeistein function is what i need, but it's messed up, i mean too many conditions. Again, Pretty princess is a clean and neat way, but i can't add keys to it.

Comment: I will have a look.  BUT it would also be worthwhile looking into how you should normalise your database design, this looks like forcing multiple data into 1 element.  If you need to do it this way, you may also consider using JSON instead as it's a standard format.  I'll let you know if I get anywhere with the current code.

Comment: Thanks @Nigel However i am returning JSONresponse from my API and my database query is as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464667/find-name-or-alias-of-matched-column-in-match-against).